# I'm trying to display product categories on each product in the list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, categories

To be more precise I'm trying to get the category name as a class.

I want it under the title, so something like:

```
echo '<h3><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>
</h3>';
echo '<span style="display:none;" class="prodcat';
$categories = array( Category1, Category2);
foreach ($categories as $category) {
echo ' ' . $category . '';
};
echo '"> </span>';
```

I just can't figure  out how to get he categories from the product to replace "array( Category1, Category2);"

I've messed around a whole lot, the closest I've gotten is displaying "Array"

Comment: I didn't understand your issue, are you not getting categories, or getting categories but not able to print name properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product categories in Woocommerce is a term, so you can get the categories with get_the_terms function:

```
echo '<h3><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>';
echo '<span style="display:none;" class="prodcat';
$categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo ' ' . $category->name . '';
};
echo '"> </span>';
```

Comment: Thanks dbeja. Easy when you know how!

Do you know how I would echo the parent category?

Comment: You can use: $parent = get_category($category->parent); and then just echo $parent->name. Also be aware that if $category->parent is 0 (it can have no parent) it will probably throw an error, so it would be good to check for that.